# Pairwise uncorrelated sub-vectors of a normal random vector are mutually independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Two vectors $\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{Z}$ are uncorrelated if their cross-covariance matrix $\mathrm{cov}(\mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{Z})$ is a zero matrix.

Let $\mathbf{X}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{X}_n$ be $n$ sub-vectors of a normal random vector $\mathbf{X}$ i.e. $\mathbf{X} = (\mathbf{X}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{X}_n)^{\mathrm{T}}$.

Then will the following statement be true?

"**Sub-vectors of a normal random vector are pairwise uncorrelated if and only if they are mutually independent**"

I know that this statement is true for $n=2$ ([proof here](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/multivariate-normal-distribution-partitioning#hid4)). I also know that this statement is true when all sub-vectors are scalars (i.e. random variables, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence)). And it is obvious that independence implies uncorrelatedness. So can we generalise these facts as stated above?

Comment: Maybe I have not completely understand your question, but seemingly the statement is obviously true..

Comment: @BGM I also think that the statement in bold is true. But I have seen about ten probability textbooks and none of them contain it. Do you think it is possible to prove the statement by an obvious generalization of the proof for $n=2$ case?

Comment: Pairwise uncorrelated means all the corresponding block matrix are zero matrix? Then it is essentially the same. When you partition a multivariate normal random vector and pick some sub-vector out, it also has a multivariate normal distribution as it is just an affine transform. So everything is just the same.